# Having difficulty showing the function $f(z)=e^{{{1}\over{z}}}$ has no limit for approaching zero along different pathes

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

having difficulty showing the function $$f(z)=e^{{{1}\over{z}}}$$ has no limit for approaching zero along the imaginary axis. also it becomes infinite if $z\rightarrow 0$ through positive real values and approaches zero if $z\rightarrow 0$ through negative real values. Should I represent $z$ as $x+iy$?

EDIT: It is relatively simple for real numbers but for $z=bi$,
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to {0^ + }} {e^{{1 \over {bi}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to {0^ + }} {e^{ - {1 \over b}i}} = {e^{ - \infty i}}$$
and
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to {0^ - }} {e^{{1 \over {bi}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to {0^ - }} {e^{ - {1 \over b}i}} = {e^{ + \infty i}}$$

Comment: It is relatively simple for real numbers .

Comment: @AnneBauval    Yes z stands for 0. I corrected the question and tried to explain the problem more clearly As an edit

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by Euler's identity
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\,\frac{1}{ix}}=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\,i\cdot\frac{-1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+=\dots$$
and now deal with the real limits

Comment: $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to 0} {e^{{1 \over {bi}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to 0} {e^{ - {1 \over b}i}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to 0} \cos ({1 \over b}) - i\sin ({1 \over b})$$ does not exist ? am I right?

Comment: Well, you have rewritten what I wrote with another letter, but indeed: $\cos$ and $\sin$ limits are undefined as their argument goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that the limit you wrote does not exist. Therefore, if z tends to zero along the imaginary axis, there is no number that can be considered as a limit

Answer (score 1):

As $t\to+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ $e^{it}$ has no limit since
$$\forall n\in\Bbb Z\quad e^{i2n\pi}=1\text{ and }e^{i(2n+1)\pi}=-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Might help to represent $z$ in polar coordinates, $z=re^{i\theta}$.

So $e^{1/z}=e^{\frac{1}{r}(\cos\theta -i \sin \theta)}$. Clearly the expression has a different sign if approaching from $\theta=0$ vs. $\theta = \pi$.

I think in general you want  $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(r=0,\theta)=0$ in order to have a limit at the origin.